# Capistrano: how to remove symlink 'current' and rather use: {deploy_to} for accessing the deployed files

Tags: php, capistrano, document-root

Hey,
I am using Capistrano to deploy my PHP applications.
Now, I notice a strange thing here (or maybe this is something I do not understand).
Capistrano deploys application to `releases` folder and then, symlinks `current` to point to latest release.
Now, when I access these files, I have to access them like this: `http://example.com/current/`
Is there a way, I can tell capistrano (or make it work) so that I can rather use: `http://example.com/` to access these deployed files?

Regards
Nikhil Gupta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `current` symlink is to enable capistrano's built-in functionality for rolling back to previous releases - it just changes the symlink to point to a different subdirectory of `releases`.

Do you have access to the server's host-configuration? If so, you could change the `DocumentRoot` to point to `/path/to/your/app/current` instead.

Comment: that works for me, but I still got another query. what if, the `:deploy_to` variable is set to be dependent on `:application` variable? o'course we would not be able to use `DocuemntRoot` in that case.

Comment: Depending upon how dynamic you need that to be, you might either use something like Apache's mass-virtualhosting functionality, or just set up multiple `VirtualHost`s manually. Either way, you might want to ask this as another question.  ;-)

Comment: naah.. the explanation itself solves my query. thank you, for this valuable comment, as well as the answer, itself :)